# Solaris installer gets screen unreadable at the boot

Tags: solaris

I just got a usb-stick installer of a Solaris 11.4(text mode, usb installer). After installer loads(somewhere around 100%), I get garbage on a screen. I had such issues with other installers. Different installers have different "magic sequences" to change a video mode. Experimenting with those can turn screen to be readable.

I do not know how can I get the installer to readable mode with Solaris. Please advice.

Comment: What is the hardware you try to install it?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Lenovo, Intel laptop

Comment: Have you try to use Automated installer?

Comment: @RomeoNinov No. Will the automated installer set an appropriate video mode?

Comment: For me it set it. Just after few minute or so (after boot) press d and then <Enter>. And wait (if you do not see clear view on the screen). Will be wise to be on wired connection with working DHCP because installer will download definitions of around 70-90k packages

Comment: @RomeoNinov tough luck, no DHCP.